# Postgres recursion returning each account's tree size

Tags: postgresql, recursion, tree, nested, recursive-query

For this example, I have a PostgreSQL database structured like a tree/pyramid.

I can get account id 1's tree/downline from the following:

```
with recursive ret (uplineid, accountid) as
(
  select a.uplineid, a.accountid from tree a
  where a.uplineid = 1
  union
  select c.uplineid, c.accountid from tree c
  join ret d on c.uplineid = d.accountid
)
select * from ret
```

I also have another table containing a list of ID's.  I'm looking to retrieve the count of people in each person's tree.

I've been performing this recursion on my front end, but it's not super ideal.  Is there a way in postgreSQL to perform this recursion for every single accountid in another table, grouping the final result by their id?

Answer (score 0):

A good startingpoint is to ensure you keep the same **root** all the way in your recursion as shown below (`d.uplineid`). You will have little use to only get the parent from your recursive CTE.

```
with recursive ret (uplineroot, uplineid, accountid) as
(
  select a.uplineid, a.uplineid, a.accountid from tree a
  where a.uplineid = 1
  union
  select d.uplineroot, c.uplineid, c.accountid from tree c
  join ret d on c.uplineid = d.accountid
)
select * from ret
```

Next step is remove the initial `where` or change it to something more convenient and voila!

```
with recursive ret (uplineroot, uplineid, accountid) as
(
  select a.uplineid, a.uplineid, a.accountid from tree a
  where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from tree WHERE accountid= a.uplineid) 
  union
  select d.uplineroot, c.uplineid, c.accountid from tree c
  join ret d on c.uplineid = d.accountid
)
select * from ret
```

More details about your tables are needed to tweak this more.